# How do I copy a file with accompanying symlinks in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, symbolic-link

Expected scenario:

```
$ ls -lh /lib/libcurl.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Mar 26  2013 /lib/libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Mar 26  2013 /lib/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.5M Mar 26  2013 /lib/libcurl.so.4.0.1

$ copy_with_links /lib/libcurl.so.4 /tmp/libcurl/

$ ls -lh /tmp/libcurl/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Mar 18  2014 /tmp/libcurl/libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Mar 18  2014 /tmp/libcurl/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.5M Mar 18  2013 /tmp/libcurl/libcurl.so.4.0.1
```

Comment: Use `rsync` with the `--links` option.

Comment: @Barmar, Will it be different from `cp -a`? I need to specify one file, but also copy associated files.

Comment: I think it will be the same as `cp -a`. `rsync` is usually better if you're copying a whole hierarchy, there's probably not much difference when copying individual files.

Answer (score 0):

Coded myself: https://gist.github.com/vi/adb4e81d2d8750d2c949

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "Usage: copy_with_links one_or_more_source_files target_directory/"
    exit 1
fi

set -e

f=("$@")

d=${f[${#f[@]}-1]}
d=$(readlink -f "$d")

# remove the target directory from list of files
unset f[${#f[@]}-1]

for a in "${f[@]}"; do.
    b=$(readlink -f "$a")
    dn=$(dirname "$b")

    for q in $(find  -L "$dn" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -samefile "$b"); do
        cp -ai "$q" "$d/"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually just do `cp -a <FILES...> <DEST_DIR>`. The `-a` tries to preserve as many file attributes as possible (including keeping symlinks as symlinks), though there are other flags that do less, if you want more granularity.

Comment: It does copy only one file. I need to copy a system of a file with associated symlinks. With only `cp -a` (or `cp -d`) I'll get a broken symlink.

Comment: `cp -a /lib/libcurl.so* /tmp/libcurl`